# VBA - insert objects next to each other

Tags: vba, excel, object

I have some VBA code, such that when a button is pressed, the user can choose a file from their computer, and insert it as an object that looks like an icon into the spreadsheet.

The code is such that it counts each time the button is clicked, so each new icon inserted by the user appears to the right of the existing one, i.e:

```
count = count + 1
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Object 1").IncrementLeft 90*count
```

Now, the problem is, I don't know how to change the count so that each time a user deletes an object from the spreadsheet, the count would decrease by 1 (so that the next object inserted would still be in line and the appropriate spacing to the right of the first object).  I would assume that I would use an event, but there doesnt seem to be an event for when an object is deleted.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Since the embedded files are OLE objects then you don't need to maintain a count. You can just calculate it on the fly using the OLEObjects collection.

If there are other ActiveX objects then you might need to need to iterate through and just count the items of type xlOLEEmbed.

```
Count = 0
For Each o In Sheet1.OLEObjects
    If o.OLEType = xlOLEEmbed Then Count = Count + 1
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

How do you handle the deletes?
Maybe you can prompt the user to press a button to delete beforehand.
So user presses a button, you see how many objects are in whatever field you're referencing, and then keep scanning each time the user initiates something.

Either way you're going to have to have some way for the to track each time the user initiates something. Or you can track by selection; IE if user selects one of the objects, see how many objects remain, after each action performed by the user.

Presumably they're only selecting it in order to delete.